# Why was StackOverflow's most-useful-free-net-libraries was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation?

Tags: support

In feb 2011 there was a broad wiki message

most-useful-free-net-libraries https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662956/most-useful-free-net-libraries

with many useful wiki entries ordered by category.

why was this removed from Stack Overflow "for reasons of moderation?"

Is it possible to put bring that page back again?

Comment: google search suggested at 404 page shown for this question shows a reference to another one as top link: "What is the most useful .net library you've found?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233648/what-is-the-most-useful-net-library-youve-found

Comment: @gnat That link isn't nearly as complete or well written. K3b, I flagged the question asking for it to be undeleted as although it is "not-constructive" by SE's standards, it is well-written, very useful, and I think it does make the internet a better place. I'd ask for a historical lock based on it's votes/views/favorites, however it looks like it's still actively being maintained because the latest edit was earlier this month. If the flag doesn't work, your best bet is to post a question on Meta.SO asking for undeletion, and objectively explaining why you don't think it should be deleted.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know. Why don't you ask on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) as the question is on Stack Overflow **not** Programmers.

That said there are a couple of questions referencing deleted content:

[Deleted Meta Questions Archive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61221/deleted-meta-questions-archive)

and

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73455/popular-deleted-so-su-programmers-questions-list

That may help you.

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong meta: -(. Lets see if Rachels vote to undelete works ....

Comment: @k3b - Rachel won't be able to vote as the question was deleted by a moderator. All she can do is flag it.

Comment: @k3b My flag got dismisses as "helpful", however the question was not undeleted. Your best chance would probably be to create a post on Meta.StackOverflow asking for it to be undeleted, and outlining why you think it should be undeleted despite not matching SE's question guidelines.